# Jquery ready function with click and ajaxForm calls

Tags: jquery-plugins, ajaxform, ready

I m really new working with JQuery and I have an error in my code. The next piece of code was working perfect when a user click a "Button", it load a file in a content div.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.Button').click(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        if( typeof href != "undefined" && href != ""){
            $.ajax({
                url: href,
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function(data) {
                            $('#content').html(data);
                            ultXML = href;
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

But now I m trying to use JQuery Form plugin (with this example http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) And it doesnt work (the ajaxForm call), I cant understand how to merge the next code in my orignal code. I try many ways, for example making 2 ready function but it also doesnt work,

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
            }); 
        });
```

Where I must put the next piece of code in my original ready function? How can meger both?

```
 $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this, work?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.Button').click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    if( typeof href != "undefined" && href != ""){
        $.ajax({
            url: href,
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data) {
                        $('#content').html(data);
                        ultXML = href;
            }
        });
    }
});

$('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
    alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
});
```

});

Comment: No, I tried that way but it doesnt work, is that the proper way of do it? In that way just the Button click work and if I put first myForm, the Button doesnt work

Comment: I take this code out of my application (just to test it) and it works, I supose there is an error in another part of the code I m doing, thanks!